# Characterization of infinite definable set

Tags: model-theory

Let $\mathcal M$ be a $\mathcal L$-structure and $D=\phi(\mathcal M)$ be a $\mathcal M$-definable set.
I want to show that $D$ is infinite iff there is $\mathcal{M}$ such that $\mathcal{M}\preceq\mathcal{N}$ and $D^\mathcal{N}=\phi(\mathcal N)$ strictly contains $D$.

I proved one implication (by using the fact that if $D$ is infinite, then $\mathrm{Diag}_\mathrm{el}(\mathcal{M})\cup\{\phi(c)\}\cup\{\,c\neq d:d\in D\,\}$ is finitely satisfiable for a fresh constant $c$) but I am stuck with the other one.

Answer (score 3):

If $D$ is finite then $D$ has $k$ elements for some specific $k$.  That fact can be expressed as a sentence (using the same parameters from $\mathcal{M}$ that $\phi$ used), so if $\mathcal{N} \models \operatorname{Diag}_{el}(\mathcal{M})$ then $\phi^\mathcal{N}$ also has $k$ elements.  In particular, if $\mathcal{M} \preceq \mathcal{N}$ then $\phi^{\mathcal{N}} = \phi^{\mathcal{M}}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so are your referring to the formula $\exists x_1,\ldots,x_k,\bigwedge_{1\leq i<j\leq k}x_i\neq x_j\land\phi(\bar a,\bar x)\land\forall y\bigvee_{1\leq i\leq k}y=x_i$?

Comment: If you want to save ink, you can write $d_1,\dots,d_k$ are the only elements satisfying $\phi(x)$.